# Want to pass data fetched from sql table in json array using html and php

Tags: javascript, php, sql, json

I want to pass a table whose data is fetched from database using JSON array. How can I pass it in the message parameter of JSON_ENCODE

```
     function check_order(){
        var mob= $('#order-status-input').val();
        if (/^[0-9]{1,10}$/.test(+mob) && mob.length==10){
           document.getElementById('check_status_conf').style.display="block";
           $.getJSON("status.php", {mobile:mob},function(data){
              if(data['status']==1){
                 document.getElementById('check_status_conf').innerHTML=data['message'];
              }
              else if(data['status']==2){
                 document.getElementById('check_status_conf').innerHTML=data['message']
              }
          });
      }
  };
```

Here is the PHP -

```
<?php
    $mobile = $_GET['mobile'];

    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    $db = mysql_select_db("XXXXX", $connection);
    $query = mysql_query("select id,order_date,status from tbl_orders where mobile=$mobile");
    $r=mysql_num_rows($query);
    if($r >= 1)
    {
       $mess=while($rw=mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {?>

<table>
    <tr><td><?php echo "".$rw['id'];?><br /></td><td><?php echo "".$rw['order_date'];?><br /></td><td><?php echo "".$rw['status'];?><br /></td></tr>
</table>
<?php
}
echo json_encode(array('status'=>1,'message'=>$mess));
}?>
```

Comment: Make sure that the mobile numbers contains only numbers, otherwise do `where mobile='$mobile'");` or SQL will complain about it.

Comment: *"this is urgent."*- Isn't it always. You'll have bigger problems later if you don't start using prepared statements **now**.

Comment: Yes sure i will make those changes. But i am totally new to json and ajax so please tell me how to pass a table using the JSON_ENCODE. can i store the table in a variable and pass the variable. If yes thn please give me a code example Thanks a  lot :)

Comment: Did you try `where mobile='$mobile'");` and include error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: Felix:I know.. i just pasted between the code.. I was editing it, therefore these mistakes

Comment: hi this works fine when i remove all the php thing in between and just use json_encode('status'=>1,message=>'some message')

Comment: But I need that table to be passed to the calling page. please reply

Comment: "Puhlease gimmeh teh codez!" really doesn't work here. In addition the `mysql_` functions are *deprecated* See what @Fred-ii- said above about prepared statements.

Comment: Have you watched the request / response cycle in your browser's console to see what the AJAX request is doing?